# Reading path written in text box removes backslash

Tags: c#, sql

In my current project, the user writes a file path (Example: `"C:\Data"`) into a Textbox. Then I read it with:

```
string PathInput = tbPath.Text;
```

And then send it into an SQL Insert Query.

If I then read the data from SQL, I get back: `C:Data`

So I tried to do:

```
string Path = PathInput.Replace(@"\", "\\");
```

So that it would double the `\\`, because when I enter `C:\\Data` I get `C:\Data`. But it looks like the `\` get lost in Textbox and not in Database.

So, how can I read the TextBox without losing the `\s`?

Comment: Try using `GetFullPath` - as per here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: `string Path = PathInput.Replace(@"\", @"\\");` instead of `string Path = PathInput.Replace(@"\", "\\");` ? Currently you are replacing one \ with one \.

Comment: What you mean read the data from SQL? did Path get double slash or not? If string is correct then show us what are you doing on SQL. Show us the insert query

Comment: @blaze_125 That was the solutin! There is no way to set comment as correct answer, right?

Comment: @TimothyLukasH. that's alright. I'll have a great day just knowing I helped someone out. No needs for points ;)

Comment: You can accept Jle answer, almost the same. But I still wondering why you need do that. You can send `C:\Data` in an insert query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your replace doesn't actually replace anything:

```
PathInput.Replace(@"\", "\\");
```

Since you use an `@` before the first string, you don't have to escape anything. But in the second string, you don't use `@`, meaning you have to escape characters in that string - that means you're replacing the `\` with another `\`.

Change it to:

```
PathInput.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```